# Umbraco Block List not shown in List in Data Types

Tags: umbraco

[image]

I don't get it! how ca I add this Editor to select it as a new Data type?

Answer (score 0):

Discoverd that the [Documentation from Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Backoffice/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Block-List-Editor/) isn't speaking about the version, which the Umbraco needs to run on. [Here](https://umbraco.com/blog/deep-dive-the-block-list-editor/) you see that the first sentence answers this question.

For eveeryone who's too lazy to read the article, the version you want your Umbraco running on is **8.7 or above**.